# Space complexity of str.substr() in C++

Tags: c++, substr

What is the space complexity of the str.substr() function and how does it compare to str.erase()?

---

Wondering because I was running a code on leetcode, and used 150MB of memory when I used the substr function:

```
num = num.substr(1,num.size());
```

As soon as I removed this function and instead used the erase function, while changing nothing else in my code, the memory usage fell to 6.8MB. Updated code with erase function:

```
num = num.erase(0,1);
```

Comment: Who knows what leetcode does in terms of optimization options? `substr` just allocates a new string: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> num = num.substr(1,num.size());
> ```

*substr* creates a copy of string without the first character, so out of the 1 character less after the call you have (almost) two times the initial string

<sup>(1)</sup> <del>the string are shared, so</del> after the assignment the initial string is deleted <del>if it is not referenced from elsewhere,</del> but before the assignment you had the two versions in memory requiring memory.

> ```
> num = num.erase(0,1);
> ```

modifies the string, so that need only one version of the string during the execution

note it is the same as doing

```
num.erase(0,1);
```

---

(1): from Pete Becker remark since C++11 the internal representation of `std::basic_string` is explicitly not allowed to be shared

Comment: @Spencer yes, having `std::string s = "..."; std::string s2 = s;`  the internal string is shared by *s* and *ss* (until one of them modify it from the external point of view)

Comment: I don't have a citation to the standard, but starting with C++11 the internal representation of `std::basic_string` is explicitly **not allowed** to be shared. Before that some implementations used copy-on-write, but with the addition of multi-threading in C++11 that became unworkable. In Java strings can share internals, but that works because Java strings are immutable; modifying a string requires replacing the internal representation.

Comment: @PeteBecker very interesting, so to have a function/method parameter typed `std::string` rather than `const std::string &` can have bad performance result with a long string since C++11

Comment: Yes, passing `std::string` by value requires copying the data, and that's more expensive than passing by reference. There are design approaches where passing by value is useful; if a function needs to make a copy of the string (a constructor, for example), some folks like to pass the string by value and then move from the temporary. I haven't dug into the implications of that approach.

Comment: @PeteBecker in fact generally since long time (before c++11 exist) I already used `const std::string &` to avoid internal counter management, you enforce me to do that. I edited my question ... but I do not know how to have footnote

Comment: I don't know how to do a footnote either. That looks fine. +1.

Answer (score 0):

> Space complexity of str.substr() in C++

Technically, it depends on the type of `str`.

Reasonably, there should be no overhead on top of the size of the output. The space complexity of `std::string` is linear in relation to the length of the string.